# Combining columns from two files and seperating them into indivdual output files

Tags: linux, csv

I have two large csv files that share the same first column and first row (header) as follow: etc means more values with same pattern.

**file1.csv**

```
names,text1,text2,text3,etc
A,1,4,3 ...
B,5,2,8 ...
C,3,7,4 ...
D,9,1,3 ...
etc
```

**file2.csv**

```
names,text1,test2,text3,etc
A,7,2,9 ...
B,3,0,6 ...
C,8,7,2 ...
D,1,5,6 ...
etc
```

I would like a code/script to combine columns (with matching headers or column #)from file1.csv and file2.csv in addition to the first column from file1.csv and output them in new files named based on the header.

So it would give the following output files and so on:

**text1.csv**

```
names,text1,text1
A,1,7
B,5,3
C,3,8
D,9,1
etc
```

**text2.csv**

```
names,text2,text2
A,4,2
B,2,0
C,7,7
D,1,5
etc
```

**text3.csv**

```
names,text3,text3
A,3,9
B,8,6
C,4,2
D,3,6
etc
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming both files are sorted (excluding the header line), as per your examples, the following should work:

```bsh
column=2
until [[ $column > $(awk -F, '{ print NF; exit }' file1.csv) ]] ; do 
  join -t , -o 1.1,1.$column,2.$column file1.csv file2.csv > $(awk -F, '{ print $'$column'; exit }' file1.csv).csv 
  ((column++))
done
```

(Borrowed a snippet from [@janos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/641955/janos) in [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42174462).)

Most of the magic here is done by `join`; output files will be written in current directory.

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to [miguelsvieira’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/697425/80216#697439),
but using Bash to count the columns and get the headers:

```
IFS=, read -a headers < file1.csv
column=0
for h in "${headers[@]}"
do
        if [ "$((++column))" = 1 ]
        then
                continue
        fi
        join -t, -o "0,1.$column,2.$column" file1.csv file2.csv > "$h".csv
done
```

#### Output:

**text1.csv**

```
names,text1,text1
A,1,7
B,5,3
C,3,8
D,9,1
```

**text2.csv**

```
names,text2,test2
A,4,2
B,2,0
C,7,7
D,1,5
```

**text3.csv**

```
names,text3,text3
A,3,9
B,8,6
C,4,2
D,3,6
```

#### Notes:

- `read -a` reads the first line of the file into an array.
- The `column` variable takes on the values 1, 2, 3, 4, … 
  Do no processing when `column` is 1
  because we don’t want to create a `names.csv` output file.
- For the data columns, run `join`,
  joining on the first column (the default),
  outputting that column and the `column` number column from each file. 
  This part is almost identical to [miguelsvieira’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/697425/80216#697439).
- Use the `headers` array (i.e., the fields of the first line of `file1.csv`)
  to name the output files.

As with [miguelsvieira’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/697425/80216#697439) and [RudiC’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/697425/80216#697452), this assumes

- the files have the same number of columns (ideally, they should match)
- the files have the same number of lines (rows) (they should also match)

and works best if the files are sorted
(but it might work if they aren’t,
provided they are *in the **same** order*). 
And, again, this must be done in Bash.

Answer (score 1):

Try also

```
join -t, --header  file[12] | awk -F, -vOFS=, '
        {D = (NF-1)/2
         for (i=2; i<=D+1; i++) {if (FNR==1) FN[i] = $i
                                 print $1, $i, $(i+D)  >  FN[i] ".csv"
                                }
        }
'
cf te*

---------- text1.csv: ----------

names,text1,text1
A,1,7
B,5,3
C,3,8
D,9,1

---------- text2.csv: ----------

names,text2,test2
A,4,2
B,2,0
C,7,7
D,1,5

---------- text3.csv: ----------

names,text3,text3
A,3 ...,9 ...
B,8 ...,6 ...
C,4 ...,2 ...
D,3 ...,6 ...
```

This depends on input files having the same count of lines and fields, so `join` can do its part correctly (given it offers the `--header` option), and `awk` can calculate the number of iterations. Then it's just a matter of looping through the fields and print them to the relevant files, whose names have been captured in the first line.

Comment: What is ``cf``?

Comment: @G-Man Says 'Reinstate Monica: an alias to "cat files".

Answer (score -1):

```
awk -F "," 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$2;b[$1]++;next}($1 in b){print $1,a[FNR],$2}' file1 file2
```

output

```
file1
names text1 text1
A 1 7
B 5 3
C 3 8
D 9 1
```

```
awk -F "," 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$3;b[$1]++;next}($1 in b){print $1,a[FNR],$3}' file1 file2
```

output

```
file2
names text2 test2
A 4 2
B 2 0
C 7 7
D 1 5
```

```
 awk -F "," 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$4;b[$1]++;next}($1 in b){print $1,a[FNR],$4}' file1 file2
```

output

```
file3
names text3 text3
A 3  9
B 8 6
C 4 2
D 3 6
```